# How to deliver events between multiple uiwindows

Tags: ios, events, uiwindow

I'm implementing multi uiwindows.

The reason is that the bottom min view have to stay always on the top whenever other views are transitioning.

Main Window is placed under the second window. It provides an excellent way to handle separate view without any confusing. Such as, presenting or push new view controller on the main window.

But main problem is not to deliver events from the second window to the main window. 
The second window has a transparent background excepting the bottom area and have to deliver events in the transparent background into the second window.

[image]
Is there anyone knows a way to handle events in layered windows?

Answer (score 0):

I did implement the below code in uiwindow.
this code make passing events into the below window when events reached in transparent window area.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView *resultView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    if (resultView == self) {
        NSLog(@"touched in transparent window !!");
        return nil;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"touched in view!!");
        return resultView;
    }

    return resultView;
 }
```